# Passenger/ngnix, Rack application could not be started: No such file or directory - git ls-files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, homebrew

I am trying to setup a Passenger development environment for my rails apps, my app uses a git gem and I having some issues with passenger, bundler and git:

```
Error message:
No such file or directory - git ls-files
Exception class:
Errno::ENOENT
```

I have git installed using Homebrew, I tried vendoring my gems but didn't work. My guess is that nginx/passenger is not finding the git binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that your Ruby process (ie. your Passenger process) has a workable `$PATH`. However, this may be difficult and is definitely a security vulnerability. I could get your app to run anything as root by putting a `git` script in your path before the real `git` executable. So, better than relying on $PATH, use the full path of git, which is probably something like `/opt/local/bin/git`.